# Trying to install wine , facing error

Tags: repository

In the step for repository key after entering the code, it says
''File 'whineq.key' already there; not retrieving."
What to do pls guide .

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are following the instructions from https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

`wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`

The message you see means that you already have a file with the same name in the folder you are running your commands from. With the `-nc` option, `wget` is refusing to overwrite this file.

You can just delete this file manually and run the command again.